# How to limit the master host using 1 slot for each job on gridengine?

Tags: gridengine

I run the gridengine on my cluster and like to have a master queue where each job can only have  1 slot on the master host. but i do not find the way to configure this.
I learned that resource limits do not affect jobs. so something like

```
limit host{master.node.001} slots=1
```

limits one slot each user :-( but if i submit like this

```
qsub -pe myenv-pe 20 -masterq xyz.q -q abc-slaves ...etc pp.
```

the result is, that I get 3 exec processes on the master host, but I want just 1 slot for each job on the master. Is there a way to configure that ?